# How does Copy-Item behave?

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of learning PowerShell and I'm curious if someone can explain how `Copy-Item` works.

Specifically, let's say we copy a large item and that copy that will take 5 minutes to complete.

If this copy command was within a PowerShell script would the `Copy-Item` complete the copy before executing the next line or would the copy take place in the background and the script continuing execution?

So in the above example where it takes 5 minutes for the file to copy let's say the script looked like this -

```
Copy-Item C:\Example-Destination C:\Copy\Example-Destination
Write-Host "Copy Complete"
```

When the copy complete message is displayed would the copy have completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When the copy complete message is displayed would the copy have completed?*

Yes, when using PowerShell cmdlets, unless using jobs or anything specifically asynchronous, each command waits for the previous one to finish before running.